# What we are passing inside the resolve or reject parentheses (JavaScript Promises)?

Tags: javascript

When we are creating the promises, what is passed inside the `resolve()` or `reject()` parentheses? How can we use it and what can we pass there - string, number, object or function? Also in one of the YouTube tutorial videos about promises I found following code:

```js
let promiseToCleanTheRoom = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  let isClean = true;

  if (isClean) {
    resolve('Clean');
  } else {
    reject();
  }
});

promiseToCleanTheRoom.then(function(**fromResolve**) {
  console.log('the room is' + **fromResolve** )
})
```

How do 'my program' knows that fromResolve argument should be the string passed to resolve()? So when any function is passed into .then(), the argument of that function will always be the value from the resolve() parentheses?

Comment: `How do 'my program' knows that fromResolve argument should be the string passed to resolve()` The promise code handles that. Are you asking to see the sourcecode for promises?

Comment: So when I would use another name for this argument for example 'cleaned' then the string from the resolve() parentheses wouldnt be passed as this argument?

Comment: Javascript doesn't care what names you give things. The 0th argument to your function will be equal to whatever value the promise resolved to. What you name that argument is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in promises against the synchronous function is that then() function does not return any result of the promise content - it just returns the "status of resolution".

When `then()` is called, the code of promise is executing and, when resolved, it executes a callback passed in it's first argument (in Your case `function(**fromResolve**) {...}`. The most of misunderstandings comes from the oftenly repeated words that "*promises can replacement for callbacks*" - it's wrong, because promises ARE using the callbacks, but making the code more readable enabling to remove **nested callbacks**.